# VB.net how to color a panel with three adjustable stripes

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, panel

I have a requirement to color a win forms panel backcolor with 3 vertical stripes, much like say the french flag. Eventually I will need to adjust the widths of the stripes.

I've been able to do this with graphics gradient but i need the borders between each color to be precise no gradient.

This is the code to do it with a gradient, how can this be adapted to get the above effect, thanks in advance.

```
    Private Sub bandwidth_graphic_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles bandwidth_graphic.Paint

    Dim linearGradientBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(bandwidth_graphic.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, Color.White, 0)
    Dim cblend As New ColorBlend(3)
    cblend.Colors = New Color(2) {Color.FloralWhite, Color.Violet, Color.FloralWhite}
    cblend.Positions = New Single(2) {0.0F, 0.5F, 1.0F}
    linearGradientBrush.InterpolationColors = cblend
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(linearGradientBrush, bandwidth_graphic.ClientRectangle)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you really should be drawing 3 stripes rather than 1 stripe of a 3-color gradient

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction